# Reshape data based on partial column names

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, apply

I have data output from an external analytical program that is formatted as below with a single row containing all information:

```
Root.a Root.b Root.c ... node359.a node359.b node359.c ...
.653   .001    .004  ...  .034      .790       .002
```

(this output goes on for over a thousand columns, and this is just test data)

What I want to do is reshape this dataset to look like this:

```
        a       b      c    ...  
Root    .653   .001   .004  ...
...
node359 .034   .790   .002  ...
```

with part of the old column name now as the row name, and the second half of the original column name as the new column names. I am unsure if `apply` will work in this case, or if there is a `for` loop to get the row values of every 1:10 columns to be placed into their own row within a new dataframe. My preference would be to not rely on the column names themselves, as each time I run the data, I will have different numbers and names for the columns as I continue adding information. None of the examples for these functions have helped me in creating my own code for this, so any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT - SOLUTION

I had to do some weird things, but I got the desired output with the below code and explanations:

```
## pivot the table into long version
testnodes<-nodes%>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    cols_vary = "slowest",
    names_to = c("node","behavior"),
    names_pattern = "(.).(.)." ## the original output had decimals between each part of the column name, the first (.) was the node name, the second (.) was the behavior symbol A through M
  )
## this produced a weird table, separating every letter of each word, but has everything in the correct order

## created strings of the names for the nodes and behaviors
## put the node names into column 1 of testnodes
testnodes$node<-names
## put the behavior letters into column 2 of testnodes
testnodes$behavior<-string_rep

> head(testnodes)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  node  behavior   value
  <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
1 Root  A        0.0142 
2 Root  B        0.0581 
3 Root  C        0.0203 
4 Root  D        0.873  
5 Root  E        0.0215 
6 Root  F        0.00653

## Convert this back to a wide table
testnodes_w<-testnodes%>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = behavior,
    values_from = value
  )
> head(testnodes_w)
# A tibble: 6 × 14
  node             A       B       C       D       E       F       G       H       I       J       K       L
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Root       1.42e-2 5.81e-2 2.03e-2 8.73e-1 2.15e-2 0.00653 0.00158 0.00307 1.26e-4 0.00034 0       3.60e-5
2 Outgroup   2.12e-2 2.30e-2 5.37e-2 2.27e-2 3.95e-2 0.0418  0.0297  0.0463  3.92e-2 0.0340  2.88e-1 3.36e-2
3 Ceropalini 4.26e-4 5.06e-4 4.07e-3 1.78e-4 5.88e-4 0.00738 0.00107 0.00521 3.22e-3 0.00550 1.2 e-3 9.59e-1
4 Ctenoceri… 2.97e-1 4.62e-2 2.86e-3 4.93e-1 3.98e-4 0.00733 0.137   0.00570 6.39e-4 0.00762 0       1.8 e-4
5 Dipogon1   3.17e-1 2.98e-2 2.60e-1 1.45e-1 6.20e-2 0.0175  0.112   0.0192  5.83e-3 0.0193  2.26e-3 3.39e-3
6 Minagenia  1.21e-4 2.3 e-5 8.18e-4 1.45e-4 7.1 e-5 0.00299 0.00162 0.00379 9.88e-1 0.00122 7.20e-5 5   e-4
# ℹ 1 more variable: M <dbl>
```

Comment: you are probably looking at `pivot_longer()`, from the `dplyr` package. We can only help so much without a proper reproducible example

Comment: I would also recommend against using row names (general advice). Row names are too important to be left as metadata, and should usually be incorporated as proper data columns. No wonder why the tidyverse packages abolished rownames

Comment: Thank you! I am just looking for packages that I could check out. I am unsure how I could provide a reproducible example with this.

Comment: Just one correction, `pivot_longer()` is in the `tidyr` package.

Comment: I don't get the hate for rownames. IMHO they're perfectly fine for numeric tables, matrices, arrays etc where you can reference cells directly by rowname/colname combinations. Not everything needs to be pushed into a data.frame/tibble just because.